# How to get the difference in seconds in PHP?

Tags: php, time, difference

```
$now = 20141112202040;
$delayed_time = 20141112202100;
```

I did $delayed_time-$now it gives me 60. I understand why. But how do I get it to give me 20 seconds instead of 60?

**EDIT**: The digits are date-time. So 2014-11-12 20:20:40.

For example: 2014-11-12 20:21:00 - 2014-11-12 20:20:40 = 60

But I want it to give me 20 seconds as it's not total of 60 seconds.

Comment: Set $delayed_time = 20141112202060

Comment: Did you ask why 100-40 gives you 60?What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @RyanAaragon Are you serious?

Comment: This...this is my favorite question ever.

Comment: We should keep this question for posterity

Comment: Already print screened it. It will definitely be deleted in a few mins.

Comment: Too bad i don't have enough rep to protect it.

Comment: That's not it. I'm not asking 100-40. I'm asking for the time difference. For example, 20:21:00 - 20:20:40 gives me 60, but the time difference is actually 20 seconds, not 60.

Comment: Does `20141112202040` look to you like a number or a date and time? Please reformat your question

Comment: My bad. I fixed it. My wording is very poor sorry

Comment: Nice *curve ball* we've been thrown.

Comment: haha I read the question myself afterwards and realise it was quite funny. xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$now = "2014-11-12 20:20:40";
$delayed_time = "2014-11-12 20:21:00";
$diff = strtotime($delayed_time) - strtotime($now); // $diff = 20;
```